# Rails using named routes within helper (but with class methods)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Trying to use [this method](http://giantrobots.thoughtbot.com/2007/7/24/disambiguate-your-helpers) (gist of which is use `self.method_name` in the `FunnyHelper`, then call it as `FunnyHelper.method_name` in the view).

However this causes at least a couple of problems - view methods like `h()` and named routes get broken *(they're ok with the module method `def method_name` but not within any class method `def self.method_name`)*.

Obviously I can avoid this by dropping the `def self.method_name` back to `def method_name`; anyone with any suggestions for how I can have my cake and eat it too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *really* want to do this, you can use

```
include ActionController::UrlWriter
```

to get access to your named routes and

```
# h is a private method 
ActionController::Base.helpers.send :h, "<"
```

for other view helpers.  But I would not recommend it.  In my opinion the design pattern that thoughtobt is suggesting here sucks and I would just use helper :blogs despite their complaint that it isn't explicit.  That is true, sort of... but Rails in general and this part of Rails in particular is architected in a completely "non-explicit" way so trying to fight against that is going to be more trouble than it's worth, as you are discovering.